# PHP command line script Windows Start In parameter

Tags: php, wamp

When running scripts from the command line in Windows, does the Start in parameter set the $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] in the script?

[image]

Comment: Why not test it for yourself? You're halfway there; just `echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` and find out.

Comment: Erm.... There is no DocumentRoot in the PHP CLI

Comment: There will be no `$_SERVER` array at all. Unless you run a server `php -S`

Comment: Using the CLI is like writing any other program that runs from the command line. ___Its not a web server___

Comment: Start in Sets the CWD

Comment: @RiggsFolly so I could do something like this: `$my_root = getcwd();` and then when I'm including resource files  `$my_root . "/my_folder/file.php"` ? And as long as I've set the **Start In** correctly, we can use it to include dependent files

Comment: Probably, try it! But if all these resources are in subfolders you can forget the `Start in` and just use `include my_folder/file.php`

Comment: @RiggsFolly thank you, the relative path worked: `include my_folder/file.php`
 I usually include things with the document root and haven't had much experience running PHP scheduled tasks on Windows. It's good to learn something new with the `getcwd()` too.

Comment: @RiggsFolly if you would like to make your comment about Start In setting the CWD as an answer then I can mark it as the correct answer. I can't mark a comment as an answer.

Comment: Never mind, you can add an answer if you like and accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out from some helpful commenters that the **Start In** sets CWD (current working directory) and that there is no $_SERVER array when using CLI unless you specifically add a switch for it.

To get the value of CWD in a script use the built in function: [getcwd()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php)

In my case I was trying to include a file that was relative the script and mistakenly thought I needed to use a full system path to it. But in the end a relative path worked instead of the full system path.

Answer (score 0):

Base on the php.net documentation, the answer is not.:

> The entries in this array are created by the web server. There is no guarantee that every web server will provide any of these; servers may omit some, or provide others not listed here

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: More importantly when running the CLI there ___is not web server___